# is there any update about how to bypass this: One or more invalid package . Make sure package names are associated with a valid Google Play store URL

Tags: flutter, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login

I was trying to add login with Facebook to my flutter app but I couldn't find the solution to this problem...

I tried searching but couldn't find something valuable that solves this issue... can anyone tell me how to add the Facebook login into a flutter app where it is yet not available on the PlayStore

Comment: Could you please share pubspec.yaml file and android/app/build.gradle file to identify the issue. Also please follow this guidelines. [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

same problem.
I just tried like capture for test, it seems to work...
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).